# I accidentally moved comments to chat. How can I undo this?

Tags: support, chat

Is there any way to undo moving comments to chat ?

Comment: Technically, this question is not answered, really :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving comments to a chat room does not delete the original comments, so there is nothing to undo.

Answer (score 3):

You probably talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842225/996493).

[image]

You do not need to worry about this, it is a feature on the Stack Overflow that when you discuss on answer for more than 10 comments, it is automatically creates an discussion chat room for you and the person who has asked the question. Discussing in the chat room will be faster.

Comment: For some reason I thought it deleted the comments.

Comment: @Matt, it you will click on that link then you will be move to that chat room for more faster conversion.